# Trying to get emulated pmem to be recognized by libpmem as pmem

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to develop some software using libpmem. I am setting up a test environment, where I can emulated pmem and have the library recognize it as such. I am either having problems, or not understanding something about how pmem is handled by mmap.

I have followed this: http://pmem.io/2016/02/22/pm-emulation.html

Everything looks great. Boot logs show type 12 memory at the ranges I have specified. I created an ext4 filesystems on the /dev/pmemXX, then mounted it with dax. So now I have:

```
$ mount | grep pmem
/dev/pmem0m on /mnt/mem type ext4 (rw,relatime,dax,data=ordered)
```

Now I run into a problem. I create a file, `/mnt/mem/data/test1`. Next, I run the simple copy example from libpmem. In this, I make a call:

```
addr = pmem_map_file("/mnt/mem/data/test2", ...)
```

The file is created and data is copied into it. The problem comes when I get the result from:

```
is_pmem = pmem_is_pmem(addr, file_size)
```

The address returned by the call to `pmem_map_file` does not register as pmem. When I step through the code, it is clear that the `addr` returned by the mapping is not in the memory range I have reserved as emulated type 12 memory. Also, the filepath to `/mnt/mem/data/test2` does not register as a dax character device when the library uses file stat, so both the mapped address and file path fail tests to be recognized as pmem.

From reading about DAX, it sounds as though filesystems mounted as DAX would have files memory mapped directly, and not copied into actual RAM. I am trying to understand what this means about the `addr` returned when the file is mapped.

I feel like I am missing something here. Shouldn't a mapped file in a filesystem built on emulated pmem, mounted as DAX, return true when I query if it is pmem?

*** EDIT

Thanks Piotr for the clarification. I can use `PMEM_IS_PMEM_FORCE`, but I would also like to look at device dax operation. I am trying to reconfigure the namespace to device dax, but not having success.

```
$ sudo strace ./local/opt/bin/ndctl create-namespace -f -e namespace0.0 -m dax
. . .
open("/sys/devices/platform/e820_pmem/ndbus0/region0/pfn0.0/align", 
O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/sys/devices/platform/e820_pmem/ndbus0/region0/pfn0.0/resource", 
O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/sys/devices/platform/e820_pmem/ndbus0/region0/pfn0.0/size", 
O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/devices/platform/e820_pmem/ndbus0/region0/dax_seed", 
O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "failed to reconfigure namespace:"..., 66failed to reconfigure 
namespace: Resource temporarily unavailable
) = 66
exit_group(245)                         = ?
+++ exited with 245 +++
```

Maybe this is a problem with the kernel I am running? (4.4.0-97 Ubuntu)

Comment: I think that the [tag:dax] tag refers to a different thing. Not sure if there is a tag for your kind of dax.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The library works as expected. Please see the note in current (1.3 at the time of writing) version of `man 3 libpmem` regarding the state of linux kernel enabling of persistent memory:

> NOTE: On Linux, pmem_is_pmem() returns true only if the entire range
>   is mapped directly from Device DAX (/dev/daxX.Y) without an
>   intervening file system. In the future, as file systems become
>   available that support flushing with pmem_persist(), pmem_is_pmem()
>   will return true as appropriate.
>
> WARNING: Using pmem_persist() on a range where pmem_is_pmem() returns
>   false may not do anything useful – use msync(2) instead.

This is hopefully going to change soon, see the [synchronous page faults patches](https://lwn.net/Articles/736332/).

In the meantime, you have two options if you want `pmem_is_pmem()` to return true:

- Use the `PMEM_IS_PMEM_FORCE=1` environment variable, this is going to force the function to return true.
- Reconfigure your emulated pmem device to device dax. For that task, you will need [ndctl](https://github.com/pmem/ndctl). The command is: `ndctl create-namespace -f -e namespaceX.Y -m dax` where the X is the region ID and Y is the ID of the namespace within the region (most likely `namespace0.0` if you only configured one emulated device).

Device DAX is a special character device that allows one to `mmap` it and safely perform userspace flushing, whereas in the case of all current linux file systems there *might* be background/asynchronous work like allocating extents, live defrag and so on - this means that on regular fs, despite mounting it as dax, you still need to call `msync()` to ensure consistency of your data. And that's what `pmem_is_pmem()` is informing you about.

You can read more about the problem [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/717953/).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I was not clear (and am still a bit fuzzy) about how the device dax functions versus filesystems mounted with the dax option. I attempted reconfiguring the namespace with ndctl as you suggest. For some reason, I keep getting an error "Resource temporarily unavailable". I have tried disabling namespace manually, and even tried to delete it, but so far I have not been able to get it to successfully reconfigure.

Comment: I've added more information about DAX to the post. I encourage you to read the LWN article I linked if you are interested in the details.
As for your problem, I'm afraid I never encountered your issue. What kernel/ndctl versions are you using? I strongly recommend using the latest kernel (4.13 at the time of writing) and the latest ndctl (v58.2).